# Android Intent Filter opening gmail attachment

Tags: android, intentfilter

Hi I have a document type of something.krp. I want to open this kind of files when clicked from gmail application from attachments. I have this **intent-filter** in the **manifest file**.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:host="gmail-ls"/>
</intent-filter>
```

How can I give pathPattern correctly. 
In the main activity when I open this email attachemt the result of this code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
text.setText(data.toString());
if (data != null) {
    getIntent().setData(null);
    try {
                    //openfile(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // warn user about bad data here
           finish();
           return;
           }
        }
```

is this result:

[image]

I want to give pathPattern but as you can see I can not give the correct pattern. If I add this line

```
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.krp"/>
```

to my intent-filter than it does not ask to open with my application.

Can I define a mimetype for this kind of file. If I gave a pathPattern the android does not ask for my application while tries to open the file.  Also mimeType is now problematic. It asks to open with my application for all type of files

Either I add mimeType or give a pathPattern please help me.

Comment: yes..Try setting mime type. by the way you can get mime type using this code.  context.getContentResolver().getType(uri);

Comment: Why is your scheme **android:scheme:"content"**, and not file?